# Nexcloud installation on raspberry-pi failing with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, nextcloud

Trying to install nextcloud on rpi4.

I'm getting below error when trying to install nextcloud on rpi4 running buster

```
Initializing nextcloud 23.0.4.1 ...,
touch: setting times of '/var/www/html/nextcloud-init-sync.lock': Operation not permitted,
Initializing nextcloud 23.0.4.1 ...,
Another process is initializing Nextcloud. Waiting 10 seconds...,
```

My docker-compose looks like this

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:latest
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /nextcloud:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=YOURROOTPASSWORD
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=YOURPASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Remove /var/www/html/nextcloud-init-sync.lock to unlock the installation process

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could fixed it by mounting /var/www/html to a separate nextcloud volume. On the same level like service add this:

```
volumes:
  nextcloud:
```

in your app volumes set the volume like this:

```
- nextcloud:/var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem with nextcloud 25.0.3.2 on Raspberry Pi 4 and did some research.

This causes the problem:

> Unfortunately Raspbian uses some very old
> packages. There is nothing we can fix in our image.

Source: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/1589#issuecomment-923371168

There is a workaround, by giving extended privileges to the nextcloud container:

> I did another investigation and deleted the lock file many times.
> After some time I found out that if I run the nextcloud container as
> priviliged, the error touch: setting times of
> '/var/www/html/nextcloud-init-sync.lock': Operation not permitted does
> not happen again and I could upgrade to 23.0.4.

Source: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/1742#issuecomment-1133837814

But beware:

> The --privileged flag gives all capabilities to the container. When
> the operator executes docker run --privileged, Docker will enable
> access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration in
> AppArmor or SELinux to allow the container nearly all the same access
> to the host as processes running outside containers on the host.
> Additional information about running with --privileged is available on
> the Docker Blog.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

---

tl;dr: Give extended privileges to nextcloud container

```
...
      app:
        image: nextcloud
        privileged: true
```